# Support vectors in kernel based SVM

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

What do the support vectors mean in **kernel** based svm? are they the vectors that are of distance 1 from the hyperplane that linearly separates the data in the higher dimensional space? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As in the linear case, they are vectors on the boundary. Below I annotated one example of the [iris](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-iris-py) dataset, classified with a Radial Basis Function (RBF) kernel

[image]